# Will reports generated via the Xero API be affected when the old reports are retired?

Tags: xero-api

I've seen the notice about old reports being retired: https://central.xero.com/s/article/Retiring-old-versions-of-reports-in-Xero

Currently my app uses the 2.0 version of these reports: https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/ProfitAndLoss

Does anyone know if these will be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reports endpoint will be unchanged after the front end retirement. The API will continue to retrieve the old v1 reports for the foreseeable future.